# rails: include html in a mail_to link

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, mailto

I'm looking for a way to include html in a mail_to link, so that I can automatically include a banner in the body of this email.

Thanks for any hints

Markus

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rails 3

```
mail_to "email@example.com", raw(image_tag("/path/to/banner.png"))
```

Rails 2.x

```
mail_to "email@example.com", image_tag("/path/to/banner.png")
```

See the documentation for the [mail_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to) helper.

Comment: What method is raw()? My Rails (2.3.5) doesn't know this method!

Comment: It's a Rails 3 helper. If you use Rails 2 is even more simple. I updated the response.

Comment: Sorry my question was wrong... But you answered correctly! You can find my real problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224751/

Answer (score 0):

In rails 4 with [actionview-encode_mail_to](https://github.com/reed/actionview-encoded_mail_to) you can do it like (Haml Syntax):

```
= mail_to 'email@example.com', encode: 'javascript' do
  = image_tag('contact_email.png')
```